# The sequence $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges in measure to $f g.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{ f_n \} \subset L^p(0,1)$, $\{ g_n \} \subset L^q(0,1)$, $1/p + 1/ q = 1$ and suppose that $\{ f_n \}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p(0,1)$ and that $\{ g_n \}$ converges to $g$ in $L^q(0,1)$, then we claim that the sequence $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges in measure to $f g.$

Proof:
to prove this claim we first show that $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges to $fg$ in $L(0,1)$. We have that $$f_n \xrightarrow{L^p} f \implies \int_0^1 |f_n - f|^p = 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$
Similarly $$g_n \xrightarrow{L^q} f \implies \int_0^1 |g_n - g|^q = 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$
Now,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        ||fg - f_ng_n||_1 &= || fg - f_ng + f_ng - f_ng_n||_1\\
        &\leq || fg - f_ng||_1 + ||f_ng - f_ng_n||_1\\
        &=|| (f_n- f)g||_1 + ||f_n(g_n - g)||_1\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Furthermore, by Holders Inequality, we have that $$||(f_n - f)g||_1 \leq ||f_n - f||_p ||g||_q.$$
and $$||f_n(g_n - g)||_1 \leq ||f_n||_p ||g_n - g||_q.$$
Thus we have that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        ||fg - f_ng_n||_1  &\leq || (f_n- f)g||_1 + ||f_n(g_n - g)||_1\\
        &\leq ||f_n - f||_p ||g||_q + ||f_n||_p ||g_n - g||_q.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Now $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||f_n - f||_p = 0, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} ||g_n - g||_g = 0, \lim_{n \to \infty} ||f_n||_p = ||f||_p.$$
Thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||fg - f_ng_n||_1 = 0$$
So, $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges to $fg$ in $L(0,1)$.

---

This is as far as i have gotten. I still would need to show that since $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges to $fg$ in $L(0,1),$ then $\{ f_n g_n\}$ converges to $fg$ in measure. Any help on that front would be appreciated. Moreover, let me know if my work up until this point is correct.

Comment: Using [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality#Statement), you can show that convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence in measure.

Comment: Ill give it a whirl. Thank you

Comment: Chebychevs inequality requires $f$ to be nonegative correct? Can I use that here?